# Trying this -->"converting YOLO V5 Ultralytics model and config format into Darknet format" # I get this error

Tags: yolov5

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
4 with open(cfg_file_name, 'w') as cfg:
5     with open(yaml_file_name,'r') as f:
----> 6         f = yaml.load(f,Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
7         net = 0
8         for l in f:

AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'

Comment: solved this issue with this command --> !pip install PyYaml==5.1 it will work

Answer (score 0):

Installing collected packages: PyYaml
Attempting uninstall: PyYaml
Found existing installation: PyYAML 5.4.1
Uninstalling PyYAML-5.4.1:
Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-5.4.1
Successfully installed PyYaml-5.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
dmjang@a4000:~/work/yolov5$ python3 gen_wts_yoloV5.py -w yolov5n.pt
YOLOv5  v6.0-255-gca0a007 torch 1.10.2+cu113 CPU

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gen_wts_yoloV5.py", line 133, in 
f = yaml.load(f,Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'

still not solved...
Next I tried pip3 command instead pip.
so It is solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).